# Не вызывается метод в классе, который наследует другой

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Не могу понять, почему мой код не работает так как задумано. 
Собственно, вот сам код:

Класс `EventManager`:

```
vector<Event> EventManager::getEvents() {
    return events;
}

void EventManager::addEvent(const Event& e) {
    if (!eventExists(e)) {
        events.push_back(e);
    }
}

bool EventManager::eventExists(Event e) {
    for (Event ev : events) {
        if (ev.getName() == e.getName()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Класс `EventHelper`:

```
void EventHelper::onConsoleMessage(string message) {
    for (Event e : EventManager::getEvents()) {
        e.onConsoleMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Класс `Event`:

```
Event::Event(string name) {
    this -> name = move(name);
}

void Event::onConsoleMessage(const string& message) {

}

string Event::getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Ну и сам класс, который наследует класс `Event`:

```
ConsoleMessageEvent::ConsoleMessageEvent() : Event("test") {

}

void ConsoleMessageEvent::onConsoleMessage(const string &message) {
    std::cout << "test10" << std::endl;
}
```

Все работает замечательно, но по какой-то из причин не хочет выполняться метод, во время его вызова через `EventHelper`. 
Сам вызов:

```
int main() {
    EventManager::addEvent(ConsoleMessageEvent());
    log("Test");
    return 0;
}

void log(const string& message) {
    EventHelper::onConsoleMessage(message);
    cout << message << endl;
}
```

По задумке должно выводить сообщение `test10` после использования метода `log` в классе `main.cpp`. На `java` такой код прекрасно работает. В `C++` совсем новичок, так что прошу объяснить где я допустил ошибку. И еще у меня есть вопрос: какая есть альтернатива `Map` и `List` в `C++`, по поводу списка `List` нашел инфу про vector, но думаю, что есть вариант куда удобнее. При необходимости могу прикрепить `.h` файлы (Не был уверен, что они тут пригодятся, так что прикрепил только `.cpp`).

Класс `Event.h`:

```
class Event {
private:
    string name;
public:
    explicit Event(string name);
    string getName();
    virtual void onConsoleMessage(const string& message);
};
```

Класс `ConsoleMessageEvent.h`:

```
class ConsoleMessageEvent : public Event {
public:
    ConsoleMessageEvent();
    void onConsoleMessage(const string &message) override;
};
```

Попытался сделать в другом проекте и итог такой же, метод попросту не вызывается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include "vector"

using namespace std;

class Event {
private:
    string name;
public:
    explicit Event(string name) {
        this -> name = move(name);
    }
    virtual void onTest(const string& message) {

    }
};

class Test : public Event {
public:
    Test() : Event("test") {

    }

    void onTest(const string &message) override {
        cout << "Log message: " + message << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<Event> t;
    t.push_back(Test());
    t[0].onTest("testMsg");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Этот код даже собираться не должен.

Comment: Для вызова метода класса без объекта, нужно  этот метод был статическим. В данном случаи  результат работы методов не  зависит от состояния экземпляра класса, поэтому это и есть решение: *Объявите их статическими*.  К тому же из вашего кода не понятно многое. Например, есть ли предварительное объявление функции log?...

Comment: @ヒミコ, ну если собрался, то с ним все в порядке) Я же написал, что классы `.h`. не прикреплял

Comment: Приведите [mre] проблемы

Comment: То что происходит в коде: https://ideone.com/mfvLdn

Comment: @dIm0n, добавил в тему вариант с минимальным количеством кода.

Comment: @flawe отлично, только пример должен быть не только минимальным, но и воспроизводимым. То есть должны быть необходимые инклюды и `using namespace std;` в данном случае

Comment: @flawe теперь гораздо проще увидеть вашу проблему -- вы используете просто `Event`, а надо указатель или ссылку

Comment: @dIm0n, можно пример? Не совсем понял в плане "указатель или ссылку"

Comment: @flawe в первых 3 строчках мейна замените соответственно `Event*`, `new Test()`, `->onTest`; https://stackoverflow.com/q/15188894/13970074

Comment: @dIm0n, огромное спасибо! Все понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `onConsoleMessage` должен быть виртуальный:

```
 virtual void Event::onConsoleMessage(const string& message);
```

и переопределен в `ConsoleMessageEvent`

```
 virtual void Event::onConsoleMessage(const string& message) override;
```

Тогда будет использован метод производного класса.

В С++ используется [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: В классе `Event.h` метод onConsoleMessage уже является виртуальным. Анотация `override` в `ConsoleMessageEvent.h` тоже присутствует. Код этих двух классов добавил в тему.